# Make Sierpinski using squares and recursion

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

So I'm trying to make a Sierpinski using squares. I want to make something like this recursively

[image: Sierpinski]

I want to change the position of my turtle so that it makes more squares at the side of the squares

[image: 3 squares]

I can't seem to change the position of the turtle so that it makes this shape. The turtle just starts making the squares outside the 4 squares I make

My code is

```
from math import sqrt
import turtle
window=turtle.Screen
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.color("black")
s=100

def Draw_sirepinski_square(t,s):
    for i in range (1,5):
        t.forward(s)
        t.left(90)

    t.left(45)
    t.forward(sqrt((s**2)+(s**2)))
    t.right(45)
    t.backward(s)
    t.right(45)
    t.forward(sqrt((s**2)+(s**2)))
    t.left(45)
    t.backward(s)

def sierpinski(n):
    if n ==1:
        Draw_sirepinski_square(t,s)

    else:    
        sierpinski(n-1)

        curPos = t.pos()
        t.penup()
        t.setpos(curPos[0]-s/(2*(n-1)), curPos[1]+s)
        t.pendown()

        Draw_sirepinski_square(t, s/(2*(n-1)))

        t.penup()
        t.setpos(curPos)
        t.setpos(curPos[0]+s, curPos[1]+s)
        t.pendown()

        Draw_sirepinski_square(t, s/(2*(n-1)))

        t.penup()
        t.setpos(curPos)
        t.setpos(curPos[0]+s, curPos[1]-s/(2*(n-1)))
        t.pendown()
        print(curPos)

        Draw_sirepinski_square(t, s/(2*(n-1)))
        t.penup()
        t.setpos(curPos)
        t.setpos(curPos[0]+s, curPos[1]+s)
        t.pendown()
        print(curPos)

sierpinski(3)
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: I can't seem to change the position of the turtle so that it makes this shape. The turtle just starts making the squares inside the 4 squares I make

Comment: Please give a [mcve] and a clear description of the issue.

Comment: Done (y) I hope this does it

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, properly tabbed, I get something closer to the Sierpinski pattern than "squares insides the 4 squares I just made."  The output looks like this: [image]

Try redefining s or setting new variables for distance traveled inside the function, instead of calling algebraic expressions of s.  As you get smaller and smaller, your s (as written) is still always 100 -- for example: t.setpos(curPos[0]+**s**

Comment: Outside* ah sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 0):

Start by describing the problem at a high level.  A Sierpinski gasket consists of a square with an X in it and a Sierpinski gasket half the size at three of the corners of the square.  So, the parameters we need are need are the length of a side and the position at which to draw the square.  Probably, the easiest thing will be to use the coordinates of the center of the square to designate the position of the square.  Also, as you have recognized in your code, it is necessary to have some kind of level number to stop the drawing, since trying to draw the actual mathematical Sierpinski gasket would give an infinite loop.

Besides cleaning up the parameters, you need to rethink the recursive calls.  `sierpinski` should call *itself* three times.  It should only call `Draw_Sierpinski_square` once directly.  All the other calls to `Draw_Sierpinski_square` should be made indirectly, through the recursive calls. Again look at the high-level description -- one square with an X and four gaskets.

As an aside, I think that the choice of the name `Draw_Sierpinski_square` was poor, and that it contributed to your confusion.  If you had just called it `Draw_square` or `squareX` or something, you'd have been less like led astray.

I think you ought to be able to take it from here, but please let me know if I need to clarify anything for you.

It's occurred to me that I ought to post a picture of my drawing, just in case I misunderstand the specs.  Here is what I think your posted code is supposed to draw:[image]